# how to permanently disable swaps on Centos?

Tags: linux, centos, swap

I've entered the following

```
swapoff -a
```

This only works until reboot. I'm not sure the best way to permanently disable swaps on Centos. Can anyone advise? thanks

Answer (score 3):

This configuration is stored in `/etc/fstab` by default in CentOS.
You can check and remove your current swap device from that configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

I cribbed this from https://www.refmanual.com/2016/01/08/completely-remove-swap-on-ce7/ with a bit of additional clarification and testing.

First disable swap temporarily:

```
# swapoff -a
```

Then remove the LVM volume for the swap:

```
# lvremove -Ay /dev/centos/swap
```

You can recover the space used by extending the root volume:

```
# lvextend -l +100%FREE centos/root
```

You then need to remove the LVM swap partition from the kernel boot command line by editing the GRUB configuration file in `/etc/default/grub` to remove the `rd.lvm.lv=centos/swap` device:

```
# vi /etc/default/grub
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=true
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"
##GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rd.lvm.lv=centos/root rd.lvm.lv=centos/swap crashkernel=auto rhgb quiet"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rd.lvm.lv=centos/root crashkernel=auto rhgb quiet"
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
```

The GRUB configuration needs to be regenerated. On a BIOS boot system:

```
# grub2-mkconfig -o /etc/grub2.cfg
```

On a UEFI system:

```
# grub2-mkconfig -o /etc/grub2-efi.cfg
```

Edit `/etc/fstab` to remove or comment out the swap device:

```
# vi /etc/fstab
/dev/mapper/centos-root  /        xfs    defaults 0 0
#/dev/mapper/centos-swap swap     swap   defaults 0 0
```

Reboot and your system should come up without any swap.